# Using trim in firebase storage bucket variable

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I implemented a bucket for every user like this

`uid-media`

I want to  allow a looged in user to read his files.

So, for the bucket name: `gm5as4lhjllw2cdfrtgyh-media`

```
  function isMemberOf(bucket, UID) {
    return bucket.trim("-media") == UID
  }
  

  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && isMemberOf(bucket,request.auth.uid);
    }
  }

}
```

It looks like the trim is not working.

Comment: The stated pattern `uid_media` doesn't match the coded pattern `uid-media`.  Underscore is not the same as hyphen. Also, there is no `trim` in the documentation for security rule [strings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#string). Maybe you want to use the documented regex, string range, or split instead.

Comment: Sorry. Its a typo

Comment: @DougStevenson The part about `trim` not existing in security rules seems like an answer, Wanna post it below?

Answer (score 0):

.trim() only use to trim leading and trailing white space.
To achive the same effect use replace

```
return bucket.replace("-media","") == UID
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String